# onBindViewHolder(VH, position) improperly calling the old and new ViewHolder copies when using notifyItemChanged()

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

**EDIT2:** I made it explicit in the condition when `holder.showTaskRecyclerView` is `false` to hide the view, so as to cover explicitly both `true` and `false` cases in `onBindViewHolder`. I still have the same problem.

**EDIT1:** I should add that the showing and hiding of `tasksRecyclerView` works well if I use `notifyDataSetChanged()`, instead of `notifyItemChanged()`, but this disables the animation and it's more costly.

I have a RecyclerView called `tasksRecyclerView` inside my ViewHolder which is supposed to be shown and hidden whenever the view is clicked. (This is a RecyclerView inside the main RecyclerView, so to say.):

```
 public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public ImageView routineStateImgView;
    public TextView alarmTextView;
    public TextView routineNameTextView;
    public RecyclerView tasksRecyclerView;
    public boolean showTaskRecyclerView = false;

    public ViewHolder(View routineItemView){
        super(routineItemView);

        routineItemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //toggle showing TaskRecyclerView
                showTaskRecyclerView = !showTaskRecyclerView;
                notifyItemChanged(getAdapterPosition());
            }
        });
        routineStateImgView = (ImageView) routineItemView.findViewById(R.id.routineStateImgView);
        alarmTextView = (TextView) routineItemView.findViewById(R.id.alarmTextView);
        routineNameTextView = (TextView) routineItemView.findViewById(R.id.routineNameTextView);
        tasksRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) routineItemView.findViewById(R.id.tasksRecyclerView);
    }

    public ImageView getRoutineStateImgView() {
        return routineStateImgView;
    }
    public TextView getAlarmTextView(){
        return alarmTextView;
    }
    public TextView getRoutineNameTextView(){
        return routineNameTextView;
    }
    public RecyclerView getTasksRecyclerView(){
        return tasksRecyclerView;
    }
}
```

Currently the onClick in the code is set to toggle a variable (`showTaskRecyclerView`) defined inside the ViewHolder and then call `notifyItemChanged(getAdapterPosition())` to update the item change with an animation.

When OnBindViewHolder is called, it checks the state of the toggled variable (`showTaskRecyclerView`, once again) and hides or unhides the RecyclerView based on the variable. You can see this logic in the code after the line with the Log.d method in this snippet:

```
public void onBindViewHolder(RoutinesRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    //Replace contents of view with data from item in adapterRoutinesList at position.
    Routine routine = adapterRoutinesList.get(position);
    TasksRecyclerViewAdapter mTasksRecyclerViewAdapter = null;

    if(routine == null){
        holder.getRoutineStateImgView().setImageResource(android.R.color.transparent);
        holder.getAlarmTextView().setText("");
        holder.getRoutineNameTextView().setText("");
        holder.getTasksRecyclerView().setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }else{
        DateFormat dayTimeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm", Locale.US);
        String dayTimeString = dayTimeFormat.format(routine.getWakeupTime().getTime());
        holder.getAlarmTextView().setText(dayTimeString);
        holder.getRoutineNameTextView().setText(routine.getName());
        if(routine.getEnableRoutine()) {
            holder.getRoutineStateImgView().setImageResource(R.drawable.check_mark);
        }
        else{
            holder.getRoutineStateImgView().setImageResource(R.drawable.x_mark);
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "position: " + position + " holder: " + holder + " show?: " + holder.showTaskRecyclerView);
        if(holder.showTaskRecyclerView) {
            TasksManager mTasksManager = adapterTasksListCache.get(routine.getId());
            if (mTasksManager == null) {
                mTasksManager = new TasksManager(routine.getId());
                mTasksManager.readTasksFromDisk(mContext);
                adapterTasksListCache.put(routine.getId(), mTasksManager);
            }

            mTasksRecyclerViewAdapter = adapterTasksViewCache.get(routine.getId());
            if (mTasksRecyclerViewAdapter == null) {
                mTasksRecyclerViewAdapter = new TasksRecyclerViewAdapter(
                        mContext,
                        position,
                        mTasksManager.getTasksListFromCache(),
                        mRequestImageCaptureCallBack,
                        mTaskEditTextListener);
                adapterTasksViewCache.put(routine.getId(), mTasksRecyclerViewAdapter);
            }
            RecyclerView.LayoutManager mTaskLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(mContext);
            holder.getTasksRecyclerView().setLayoutManager(mTaskLayoutManager);
            holder.getTasksRecyclerView().setAdapter(mTasksRecyclerViewAdapter);
            holder.getTasksRecyclerView().setHasFixedSize(true);
            holder.getTasksRecyclerView().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        else{
            holder.getTasksRecyclerView().setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
}
```

I expect to see the RecyclerView hide or unhide on every click. However I only see the hide/unhide behaviour after every 2 clicks.

[image: hide-unhide-with-2-clicks]

Here's the output of the Log.d after clicking 5 times:

```
04-16 21:33:37.026 13522-13522/co.edu.javeriana.faros D/RoutinesViewAdapter: position: 0 holder: ViewHolder{263b1503 position=0 id=-1, oldPos=-1, pLpos:-1 no parent} show?: false
04-16 21:33:42.626 13522-13522/co.edu.javeriana.faros D/RoutinesViewAdapter: position: 0 holder: ViewHolder{883eb98 position=0 id=-1, oldPos=-1, pLpos:-1 no parent} show?: false
04-16 21:33:44.511 13522-13522/co.edu.javeriana.faros D/RoutinesViewAdapter: position: 0 holder: ViewHolder{263b1503 position=0 id=-1, oldPos=-1, pLpos:-1 no parent} show?: true
04-16 21:33:46.274 13522-13522/co.edu.javeriana.faros D/RoutinesViewAdapter: position: 0 holder: ViewHolder{883eb98 position=0 id=-1, oldPos=-1, pLpos:-1 no parent} show?: true
04-16 21:33:47.938 13522-13522/co.edu.javeriana.faros D/RoutinesViewAdapter: position: 0 holder: ViewHolder{263b1503 position=0 id=-1, oldPos=-1, pLpos:-1 no parent} show?: false
04-16 21:41:52.756 13522-13522/co.edu.javeriana.faros D/RoutinesViewAdapter: position: 0 holder: ViewHolder{883eb98 position=0 id=-1, oldPos=-1, pLpos:-1 no parent} show?: false
```

My interpretation is that using notifyItemChanged prompts the use of 2 copies of the same ViewHolder for transition animation purposes (one with the old state of the view and one with the new one). However the copy with  the variable is wrongly changing in the old copy. I assume I have a wrong understanding of how notifyItemChanged works so I come here for help :/

Also, I have no idea what is causing the problem when I click really quick: I see no change if I click quick enough (about as quick as  less than half a second)

The logcat shows the following:

```
04-16 21:43:54.597 13522-13522/co.edu.javeriana.faros D/RoutinesViewAdapter: position: 0 holder: ViewHolder{883eb98 position=0 id=-1, oldPos=-1, pLpos:-1 no parent} show?: true
04-16 21:43:54.862 13522-13522/co.edu.javeriana.faros D/RoutinesViewAdapter: position: 0 holder: ViewHolder{263b1503 position=0 id=-1, oldPos=-1, pLpos:-1 scrap [changeScrap] tmpDetached not recyclable(1) no parent} show?: true
04-16 21:43:55.387 13522-13522/co.edu.javeriana.faros D/RoutinesViewAdapter: position: 0 holder: ViewHolder{883eb98 position=0 id=-1, oldPos=-1, pLpos:-1 no parent} show?: true
04-16 21:43:55.668 13522-13522/co.edu.javeriana.faros D/RoutinesViewAdapter: position: 0 holder: ViewHolder{263b1503 position=0 id=-1, oldPos=-1, pLpos:-1 scrap [changeScrap] tmpDetached not recyclable(1) no parent} show?: true
04-16 21:43:55.949 13522-13522/co.edu.javeriana.faros D/RoutinesViewAdapter: position: 0 holder: ViewHolder{883eb98 position=0 id=-1, oldPos=-1, pLpos:-1 no parent} show?: true
04-16 21:43:56.189 13522-13522/co.edu.javeriana.faros D/RoutinesViewAdapter: position: 0 holder: ViewHolder{263b1503 position=0 id=-1, oldPos=-1, pLpos:-1 scrap [changeScrap] tmpDetached not recyclable(1) no parent} show?: true
04-16 21:43:56.479 13522-13522/co.edu.javeriana.faros D/RoutinesViewAdapter: position: 0 holder: ViewHolder{883eb98 position=0 id=-1, oldPos=-1, pLpos:-1 no parent} show?: true
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have worked around the issue by defining a `ListArray` outside the `ViewHolder` with a `showTaskRecyclerView` for each item in the adapter.

In this way, both the old and new `ViewHolder` are looking at the same, single `showTaskRecyclerView` per item and not 2 unsynchronized `showTaskRecyclerView` per item residing in both `ViewHolder`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the logic for the condition when `holder.showTaskRecyclerView` is `false`.

The `View` maintain their state and therefore you must modify them explicitly. Place some logic to hide there and check if it works.

Comment: From my understanding, the recyclerview receives a null adapter if I want to "hide" it. The `mTasksRecyclerViewAdapter` adapter is set to null by default at the beginning. If I get to the condition where `holder.showTaskRecyclerView` is true, the adapter is set. Thus adding an else clause does nothing in terms of logic.
If you look at the 2nd to last line of code in the second snippet, the view's adapter is always set to something, either null or a fetched adapter.

Comment: `View` get recycled and thus maintain state.

Here's a simple example that demonstrates this issue. http://pastie.org/private/ftgz5lnnlcjch8yqs1jyzq

Have you tried flinging? You might see problems.

Not having both side of the logic will cause improper invalidation or rebinding of data.

Comment: Yeah flinging works fine. I also implement both sides of the logic explicitly (I edited my post to show the new code) but the problem still occurs.